# Generic event emitter without type cast

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm encountering a TypeScript error that I can't seem to resolve. I have a class Emitter with and a type `EventsByName`, which represents a mapping of event names to their corresponding events. The addEventListener method in the Emitter class is supposed to attach listener to event.

```
interface Event1 {
    name: 'event1'
}

interface Event2 {
    name: 'event2'
}

type EventsByName = {
    event1: Event1
    event2: Event2
}

class Emitter {
    private readonly eventListenersByEventName: {
        [EventName in keyof EventsByName]?: Array<(event: EventsByName[EventName]) => void>
    } = {}

    addEventListener = <T extends keyof EventsByName>(
        eventName: T,
        listener: (event: EventsByName[T]) => void,
    ): void => {
        const listeners = this.eventListenersByEventName[eventName]
        if (listeners) {
            listeners.push(listener)
        } else {
            // The intersection 'Event1 & Event2' was reduced to 'never' because property 'name' has conflicting types in some constituents.(2322)
            this.eventListenersByEventName[eventName] = [listener] as any // do not type cast 
        }
    }
}

const emitter = new Emitter()

// Should be OK
emitter.addEventListener('event1', (event) => {})
// Should fail because `event5` is not present in EventsByName
emitter.addEventListener('event5', (event) => {})
```

I understand the error I just wonder if there is a possibility to rewrite the code and avoid type cast.

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLmQbwFDLIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3HgL556iSyIoZZgBGZBAAekEABMqaTNnyFiZSgHIIswcuZsO4aPCQz%20AJmFisUw3IJFSFZKvVHNrdpz09LYKgCEAngDlbXGsHfgFlSj5wAWZCUPAnSMctdgQAGzgqaVQSYDAuYMIABzp0OEhkKAg4CQB7EDTfYXUAGWAaLGgfXyiwABVfIrt5QmQAbQBpZFBkAGsIX1qYT27AsgBdAH5KAEEoKDhfAB4ACjV%20JP5V20n1gEpkAF4APmR0WuAJZ9jkFifcFjMaw1CS9NodEDQf5HKaicQWeaLZa9a5kZ4nayEMCDOwTAA0mOQaXa4mglDO6ku4FREFuDxebw%20Emsd0o70%20T1eI0ICHqNCJJM6UGkj2QYAAFu0AHTncDg0nCvy9AZDMbYobrH6EYDLE7EiFdB7c0b6hVUKVFACuVHFesFkKgdy1v2EaSoKGNWMl5tlYHlQu6ypxapx63%20Y1NQs1hLYhEBrCAA)

Comment: Does either of [these approaches](https://tsplay.dev/Nn8MBW) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?